# Find out points outside the polygon

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, ogr, shapely

I have a shapefile with geometries of different regions. Also I have a list of coordinate points(**field_lonlat**), I want to consider only those points of the list which are outside the polygon geometries using python.
Below is my code to check it but trying to find a simpler version of it.

```
from osgeo import ogr
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.prepared import prep
from shapely.wkb import loads
import json
g = ogr.Open("Polygons.shp")
points = []
for layer in g.GetLayer(0):
    field = loads(layer.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb())
    fieldP = prep(field)
    for x,y in field_lonlat: //field_lonlat is my list of points 
        item = Point(x, y)
        if fieldP.contains(item):
            pass
        else:
            points.append((x,y))
```

But my points list checks for a single polygon once and hence considers only those points which are not in it but which might be inside an another polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would make slightly more sense :

```py
from osgeo import ogr
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.prepared import prep
from shapely.wkb import loads
import json

g = ogr.Open("Polygons.shp")
list_to_remove = []
points = field_lonlat[:] # make a copy of the list
for x,y in field_lonlat: 
    item = Point(x,y)
    for layer in g.GetLayer(0):
        field = loads(layer.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb())
        fieldP = prep(field)
        if fieldP.contains(item):
            # remove points that are in one of the polygons
            points.remove((x,y))
            # break to avoid checking every polygon if you're already inside of one
            break
```

Comment: I came up with the same idea but : if multiple points are inside one polygone, the `break` only remove the first point. And for a more Pythonic writing : `points = field_lonlat.copy()`.

Comment: sorry, i really like slicing (it is real fast!) x), it really shouldn't remove only the first point, since the break is only on the inside loop, every single point of the list should be checked against the polygons

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you inverted the two loops !

Comment: Also, how can I say that point is outside the geometry if it's on the geometry of the polygon as we are only checking the inside condition.

Comment: in the `points` list we remove every single points that are inside one/multiple of the polygons. So at the end we end up with a list contained only the points that have been found to NOT be inside any of the polygons

Comment: I have a query, my field where the check is being performed is in 3D geometry and list of points are in 2D, hence the check is not happening. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry i am not very much aware of 'shapely' geometries but i assume you might be able to transform or extract the 2D geometry from the 3D one since you basically just need to drop the z axis